Görtz and Wedhorn Hilbert Nullstellensatz: what is lemma 1.9 being applied to?
I am a physicist who made the hubris-filled decision to try and learn algebraic geometry; I am on the proof of Hilbert Nullstellensatz (in Görtz and Wedhorn) and am already stuck in the mud.
For the setup, $A$ is a finite-generated $K$-algebra ($K$ not necessarily algebraically closed). We are considering some prime ideal $P \subset A$ and would like to show that in $R := A/P$, the intersection of all maximal ideals is zero. To start, we consider some element $x \in R$ and the map $\phi$ defined as the composition of the natural localization map $R \rightarrow R[t]/(xt - 1)$ and another map into some field extension $R[t]/(xt-1) \rightarrow (R[t]/(xt-1)) / m$, with $m$ being any maximal ideal of the localization ring.
The proof in Görtz and Wedhorn is acceptable to me, except for the last part of this one statement:

If $L$ is a finite field extension of $K$ and $\phi: A\rightarrow L$ is a $K$-algebra homomorphism, the image of $\phi$ is an integral domain that is finite over $K$. Thus $\mathrm{Im}\ \phi$ is a field by lemma 1.9.

For reference, lemma 1.9 states:

Let $A$ and $B$ be integral domains and let $A \rightarrow B$ be an injective integral ring homomorphism. Then $A$ is a field if and only if $B$ is a field.

What "injective integral" map is lemma 1.9 being applied to?
I don't think it is $\phi$, since I don't believe the localization map is integral and the quotient map probably isn't injective.
If it is the inclusion map $\iota: \mathrm{Im}\ \phi \rightarrow (R[t]/(xt-1))/m$, then how can we see that it is an integral ring homomorphism?

The inclusion $\operatorname{im} \phi \hookrightarrow L$ is injective and integral; since $L$ is a field then $\operatorname{im} \phi$ is a field.

@kobe. Thank you for the response. Why is the inclusion map integral? We must show that every element of $L$ is the root of a monic polynomial with coefficients in $\mathrm{im}\ \phi$.

$L/K$ was assumed to be finite, which implies that every element $x\in L$ is a root of a monic polynomial with coefficients in $K$ (because the powers $1, x, x^2, \dotsc$ are $K$-linearly dependent). As $\operatorname{Im}\varphi$ contains $K$, it is immediate that every element of $L$ is also a root of a monic polynomial with coefficients in $\operatorname{Im}\varphi$.

@Claudius. Thank you. Are you saying that it's just true in general that the embedding of a field into one of its finite extensions is always integral?

Yes, finite field extensions are algebraic (i.e. integral).

@Claudius. Thank you. I would upvote your comment, but I don't have the privileges, so here is a poor man's upvote: ▲.

Thank you very much :D

By Zariski's lemma, $L=(R[t]/(tx-1))/m$ is a finite extension of $K$. We have a $K$-algebra homomorphism $\phi:R\to L$. The image $\operatorname{im}(\phi)\subset L$ is an integral domain (it is a subring of an integral domain) with an injective map (the inclusion) in to $L$. So it remains to check that $L$ is an integral extension of $\operatorname{im}(\phi)$. But $K\subset \operatorname{im}(\phi)\subset L$ as $K$-vector spaces, and $L$ is module-finite over $K$, so $L$ is also module-finite over $\operatorname{im}(\phi)$ and therefore $\operatorname{im}(\phi)\subset L$ is integral.
